# Max/min в двумерном массиве и индекс ячейки

Tags: c++, массивы

Имеется двумерный массив, например:

```
{10 15 40}
{8 9 11} 
{1 3 0}
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести на экран

1. Индексы "ячейки" числа
2. То самое минимальное/максимальное число
   Т.е. результатом работы программы было бы:

```
    {0 0 10}
    {0 2 40}
    {1 0 8}
    {1 2 11}
    {2 2 0}
    {2 1 3}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это то что вам нужно ?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    const int rows = 3, columns = 3;
    int arr[rows][columns] = {{10, 15, 40}, {8, 9, 11}, {1, 3, 0}};
    int maxi = arr[0][0];
    for(int i=0; i<rows; ++i){
        for(int j=0; j<columns; ++j){
            maxi = arr[i][j]>maxi ? arr[i][j] : maxi;
            std::cout << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << arr[i][j] << '\n';
        }
    }
    std::cout << maxi;
    return 0;
}
```